# Could not sort array as per max value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to sort array value as per max value using JavaScript but its giving me the wrong result. Here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
      var inputdata = [
        [1001, 20],
        [1002, 30],
        [1001, 50],
        [1003, 30],
        [1002, 60],
        [1003, 40],
        [1001, 70]
      ];
      var storedata = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < inputdata.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
          var data = {
            'key': inputdata[i][0],
            'value': inputdata[i][1]
          };
          storedata.push(data);
        } else {
          for (var j = 0; j < storedata.length; j++) {
            if (storedata[j]['key'] == inputdata[i][0]) {
              if (storedata[j]['value'] < inputdata[i][1]) {
                storedata[j]['value'] = inputdata[i][1];
              }
              break;
            } else {
              var data = {
                'key': inputdata[i][0],
                'value': inputdata[i][1]
              };
              storedata.push(data);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(storedata);
    }
```

Here I am trying to sort value like the max value of `1001,1002,1003` but in my case the expected result is not coming.

Comment: Just use the builtin sort? `inputdata.sort()`

Comment: can you add to the question what is your expected result and what you get instead?

Comment: He doesnt want to sort, he wants to merge.

Comment: Still not clear what is your expected output. Someone saying sort and someone saying merge.

Comment: @JonasWilms whereabouts is the merge?

Answer (score 1):

Because in your inner loop, when you go over the array again with `j`, then *one* of the entries might be already the one you are looking for, but *all the others you are iterating over* are not, and for those you are duplicating the entries. In other words: Move the `else {` part out of the loop, to first check the whole array wether the entry exists, and only if not add a new one:

```
  var exists = false;
  for(var j = 0; j < storeddata.length; j++) {
    if(/*...*/) {
      // merge
      exists = true;
      break;
    } // don't insert here
 }

 if(!exists) {
   // insert
 }
```

Also that `if(i === 0)` part is unneccessary (then), as `storeddata` will yet be empty, therefore it will directly go into the `if(!exists)` part and insert a new entry.

---

I'd write it as (for sure your way works too and can be fixed as described above):

```
 const result = [];

 for(const [key, value] of inputdata) {
   const duplicate = result.find(entry => entry.key === key);
   if(duplicate) {
     duplicate.value = Math.max(duplicate.value, value);
   } else {
     result.push({ key, value });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat unclear if you want sorted by the first, then the second with the array of arrays or if you want to simply list the unique value of the sub arrays first value only sorted here or if you need all the values from the sub arrays first value.

SO, I will provide all of them (sorted by both values in the sub array) then the second, ALL values sorted, then third, unique values of the first element of the sub arrays sorted.

```js
var inputdata = [
  [1001, 20],
  [1002, 30],
  [1001, 50],
  [1003, 30],
  [1002, 60],
  [1003, 40],
  [1001, 70]
];

/* sort by the first and second values */
var sortedArray = inputdata.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a[0] == b[0]) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
  }
  return b[0] - a[0];
}).reverse();
console.log(sortedArray);

/* just get the unique first values sorted */
let iA = [];
inputdata.forEach(function(element) {
  iA.push(element[0]);
});
/* all first values, sorted */
console.log(iA.sort());
/* unique first values sorted */
let uniqueSorted = [...new Set(iA)].sort();
console.log(uniqueSorted);
```